No puedo editar elementos en WordPress con Elementor
Estaba editando mi página y cuando la refresqué, al pasar el mouse sobre los elementos ya no aparecían los botones de edición. Estos solo me aparecen cuando creo contenedores o elementos nuevos, pero los viejos están como si estuvieran en modo visualización. Ya reinstalé todos los plugins, cloné la página y sigue igual. Agradecería mucho su ayuda!

Seguramente estás en una sección diferente a la que quieres trabajar. Elementor pone secciones, y para trabajar dentro de ellas, debes seleccionar la sección primero y luego trabajar el elemento.

Okey, y cómo hago para cambiar de sección?

Sin ver, ya que no has mostrado nada, debes ver la parte superior de lo que quieres editar y tendrá el nombre de la sección el cual podras seleccionar.
